# Javascript: cannot override concatenation

Tags: javascript, concatenation, addition

Using the following code I want to move a line with `id='seekline'` by `var1` (less than .1 in most cases), but I run into trouble adding `var1` and `j`.

The plus sign concatenates instead of adding. I have tried using `Number()`, `parseInt()`, `parseFloat()`, and forcing addition by multiplying by 1 or adding by 0. For some reason I cannot stop the concatenation. When I use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` (e.g. `parseInt(j,10)`) the code stops working.

The string split is to remove the `px` from `element.style.left`.

```
function move(var1) {
    element = document.getElementById('seekline');
    console.log(var1, element.style.left);
    var str=(element.style.left);
    var n=str.split("p");
    var j = n[0];
    Number(j);
    Number(var1);
    var k = var1 + j;
    var f = k.concat("px");
    console.log(j, k, f);
    element.style.left = f;
}
```

Comment: What does style.left return, a pixel value, auto, percentage? and concat() joins arrays, you can't set the left position to an array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the result of the call to `Number()`,  as it returns the numeric value of the string passed instead of modifying the variable itself.

Note that `+foo` is the same as doing `Number(foo)`.

```
function move(var1) {
  var style = document.getElementById('seekline').style;

  // removes last two 'px' characters
  var oldValue = +style.left.slice(0, -2);

  // converts to number type, then adds 2 to it
  var1 = +var1;
  var1 += 2;

  // check to see if number is NaN or +/-Infinity
  if (isFinite(var1)) {
    // only now string concatenates the term 'px' to it
    element.style.left = oldValue + var1 + 'px';
  }
}
```

Comment: +style.left.slic(0, -2); does seem to work. Unfortunately I cannot increment by less than .1. Whole numbers work perfectly. Thanks to all contributors! The following code works for moving an element to the right by var1 when var1 is a whole number: function move(var1) {
element = document.getElementById('seekline');
var oldValue = +element.style.left.slice(0, -2);
element.style.left = parseInt(oldValue) + var1 + 'px';
}

Answer (score 0):

```
function move(var1) {
    var element = document.getElementById('seekline'),
        left    = parseInt(element.style.left.replace('px',''),10);

    element.style.left = ((left++) + var1) + 'px';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The secret for you to work with numbers obtained from JavaScript, is to remove the string 'px' and convert them to numbers:

```
parseInt(element.style.left.replace('px', ''))
```